# mysql query takes too long for a million row table using count() and group by

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I want to retrieve phone_num and their count of unread message for each phone number from the table user_message.
Below mentioned query takes 10 seconds to give result which is super duper slow for me.

Extra Info of table:

1. I have Indexed Column phone_num and user_message_id

```
SELECT phone_num,
       Count(phone_num) AS no_of_messages
FROM   user_message
WHERE  user_message_id = "rd62tdw4n3"
       AND msg_status = "unread"
GROUP  BY phone_num
```

Comment: Did you consider adding an index for columns `user_message_id, msg_status`?

Answer (score 2):

You need a compound index as follows

```
ALTER TABLE user_message
ADD INDEX covering_index (user_message_id,msg_status,phone_num);
```

The query will read everything from this index and never touch the table

Comment: Thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA . It worked !